# PHP program not able to connect to mysql on aws instance

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services

I am doing this for the first time on aws instance. I have an aws instance which hosts most of my code. I have mysql installed on that instance (via SSH) and have a database over there. (It is not an RDS instance)

Now I want to be able to -

1. Connect to my database from my local machine
2. Connect to my database from the aws instance (my code which will be deployed on the instance)

But mysql is refusing the connection from local - **SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.**

In that case, do I need to grant permission to the specific IPs (my local, and my aws insatnce) using "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON something.something TO 'mysql-user'@'ip-address' IDENTIFIED BY ..." ? Or is there a better way to do that? Because I have developers sitting in different locations who will be working from their local.

What are the good practices (or industry standards)? Or can I define security groups, if at all that is possible in mysql?

Also, where can I find a good read to setup different kinds of users for my mysql. I have a root user through which I only to be able to connect via SSH. I want another user with less privileges which will be connecting through my code. I am interested to know, what should be the permissions for that kind of user?

**PS - I am able to connect to a local database using the same code if I change host ip, user and password etc. So my guess is code is working fine.**

Comment: are you connecting on localhost? or on the IP address of the ec2 instance? If the latter make sure the security groups has the mysql port open to that security group.

Comment: I am connecting with IP address of ec2 instance from the code on my localhost. And how and where to make sure that mysql port is open for that group?

Comment: You'll have to read more here on how to edit your security group http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html